# Copies of original unit dont have the same properties? Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, clone

I am currently making an RTS-style game in Unity. I have a script controlling fog of war, making enemies invisible when they are out of the vision range. The problem I am facing is that when I have multiple units, only the original I copied will reveal enemies when they are within the vision range. All the other copies will reveal the area like normal, but not eneimies in the area.

Here is the vision script I have on my units:

```
public delegate void TargetsVisibilityChange(List<Transform> newTargets);

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class FieldOfView : MonoBehaviour
{
public float viewRadius;

[Range(0, 360)]
public float viewAngle;

public float viewDepth;

public LayerMask targetMask;
public LayerMask obstacleMask;

[HideInInspector]
public List<Transform> visibleTargets = new List<Transform>();

public int meshResolution;
public int edgeResolveIterations;
public float edgeDstThreshold;


public MeshFilter viewMeshFilter;
public bool debug;
Mesh viewMesh;

public static event TargetsVisibilityChange OnTargetsVisibilityChange;

public FogProjector fogProjector;
public float updateDistance = 1;
Vector3 lastUpdatePos;

void OnEnable()
{
    viewMesh = new Mesh {name = "View Mesh"};
    viewMeshFilter.mesh = viewMesh;

    fogProjector = fogProjector ?? FindObjectOfType<FogProjector>();

    StartCoroutine("FindTargetsWithDelay", .2f);
}


IEnumerator FindTargetsWithDelay(float delay)
{
    while (true)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
        FindVisibleTargets();
    }
}

void LateUpdate()
{
    DrawFieldOfView();
    if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, lastUpdatePos) > updateDistance || Time.time<.5f)
    {
        lastUpdatePos = transform.position;
        fogProjector.UpdateFog();
    }
}

void FindVisibleTargets()
{
    visibleTargets.Clear();
    Collider[] targetsInViewRadius = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, viewRadius, targetMask);

    for (int i = 0; i < targetsInViewRadius.Length; i++)
    {
        Transform target = targetsInViewRadius[i].transform;
        Vector3 dirToTarget = (target.position - transform.position).normalized;

        if (Vector3.Angle(transform.forward, dirToTarget) < viewAngle / 2)
        {
            float dstToTarget = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target.position);
            if (!Physics.Raycast(transform.position, dirToTarget, dstToTarget, obstacleMask))
            {
                visibleTargets.Add(target);
            }
        }
    }

    if (OnTargetsVisibilityChange != null) OnTargetsVisibilityChange(visibleTargets);
}

void DrawFieldOfView()
{
    float stepAngleSize = viewAngle / meshResolution;
    List<Vector3> viewPoints = new List<Vector3>();
    ObstacleInfo oldObstacle = new ObstacleInfo();
    for (int i = 0; i <= meshResolution; i++)
    {
        float angle = transform.eulerAngles.y - viewAngle / 2 + stepAngleSize * i;
        ObstacleInfo newObstacle = FindObstacles(angle);

        if (i > 0)
        {
            bool edgeDstThresholdExceeded = Mathf.Abs(oldObstacle.dst - newObstacle.dst) > edgeDstThreshold;
            if (oldObstacle.hit != newObstacle.hit ||
                oldObstacle.hit && edgeDstThresholdExceeded)
            {
                EdgeInfo edge = FindEdge(oldObstacle, newObstacle);
                if (edge.pointA != Vector3.zero)
                {
                    viewPoints.Add(edge.pointA);
                }
                if (edge.pointB != Vector3.zero)
                {
                    viewPoints.Add(edge.pointB);
                }
            }
        }


        viewPoints.Add(newObstacle.point);
        oldObstacle = newObstacle;
    }

    int vertexCount = viewPoints.Count + 1;
    var vertices = new Vector3[vertexCount];
    var triangles = new int[(vertexCount - 2) * 3];

    vertices[0] = Vector3.zero;
    for (int i = 0; i < vertexCount - 1; i++)
    {
        vertices[i + 1] = transform.InverseTransformPoint(viewPoints[i]);

        if (i < vertexCount - 2)
        {
            triangles[i * 3] = 0;
            triangles[i * 3 + 1] = i + 1;
            triangles[i * 3 + 2] = i + 2;
        }
    }

    viewMesh.Clear();

    viewMesh.vertices = vertices;
    viewMesh.triangles = triangles;
    viewMesh.RecalculateNormals();
}


EdgeInfo FindEdge(ObstacleInfo minObstacle, ObstacleInfo maxObstacle)
{
    float minAngle = minObstacle.angle;
    float maxAngle = maxObstacle.angle;
    Vector3 minPoint = Vector3.zero;
    Vector3 maxPoint = Vector3.zero;

    for (int i = 0; i < edgeResolveIterations; i++)
    {
        float angle = (minAngle + maxAngle) / 2;
        ObstacleInfo newObstacle = FindObstacles(angle);

        bool edgeDstThresholdExceeded = Mathf.Abs(minObstacle.dst - newObstacle.dst) > edgeDstThreshold;
        if (newObstacle.hit == minObstacle.hit && !edgeDstThresholdExceeded)
        {
            minAngle = angle;
            minPoint = newObstacle.point;
        } else
        {
            maxAngle = angle;
            maxPoint = newObstacle.point;
        }
    }

    return new EdgeInfo(minPoint, maxPoint);
}


ObstacleInfo FindObstacles(float globalAngle)
{
    Vector3 dir = DirFromAngle(globalAngle, true);
    RaycastHit hit;

    if (DebugRayCast(transform.position, dir, out hit, viewRadius, obstacleMask))
    {
        return new ObstacleInfo(true, hit.point + hit.normal * -viewDepth, hit.distance, globalAngle);
    }
    return new ObstacleInfo(false, transform.position + dir * (viewRadius - viewDepth), viewRadius, globalAngle);
}

bool DebugRayCast(Vector3 origin, Vector3 direction, out RaycastHit hit, float maxDistance, int mask)
{
    if (Physics.Raycast(origin, direction, out hit, maxDistance, mask))
    {
        if (debug)
            Debug.DrawLine(origin, hit.point);
        return true;
    }
    if (debug)
        Debug.DrawLine(origin, origin + direction * maxDistance);
    return false;
}

public Vector3 DirFromAngle(float angleInDegrees, bool isGlobal)
{
    if (!isGlobal)
    {
        angleInDegrees += transform.eulerAngles.y;
    }
    return new Vector3(Mathf.Sin(angleInDegrees * Mathf.Deg2Rad), 0, Mathf.Cos(angleInDegrees * Mathf.Deg2Rad));
}

public struct ObstacleInfo
{
    public bool hit;
    public Vector3 point;
    public float dst;
    public float angle;

    public ObstacleInfo(bool _hit, Vector3 _point, float _dst, float _angle)
    {
        hit = _hit;
        point = _point;
        dst = _dst;
        angle = _angle;
    }
}

public struct EdgeInfo
{
    public Vector3 pointA;
    public Vector3 pointB;

    public EdgeInfo(Vector3 _pointA, Vector3 _pointB)
    {
        pointA = _pointA;
        pointB = _pointB;
    }
}
}
```

Here it is the script I have on enemies:

```
public class FogCoverable : MonoBehaviour
{
    Renderer rend;

    void Start()
    {
        rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        FieldOfView.OnTargetsVisibilityChange += FieldOfViewOnTargetsVisibilityChange;
    }

    void OnDestroy()
    {
        FieldOfView.OnTargetsVisibilityChange -= FieldOfViewOnTargetsVisibilityChange;
    }

    void FieldOfViewOnTargetsVisibilityChange(List<Transform> newTargets)
    {
        rend.enabled = newTargets.Contains(transform);
    }
}
```

I dont quite get how only the original vision is the one who can reveal units. 
I know its a lot of code, but any help is appreciated.

Comment: If any more information is needed, just ask

Comment: I am not quite sure but I would change the architecture. Each Unit could hold the references to the Enemy within range. Actually, if possible, I would turn Unit into a prefab. So you have all the enemies for that Unit as children. On start, they get found by the parent Unit script and added to the collection of enemies. Then when the Unit gets visible, no need for search of Enemy, just iterate the collection and set renderer on.